# AWS API Gateway : Use 302 redirect and set-cookie header

Tags: amazon-web-services, setcookie, http-status-code-302

I used AWS API Gateway to redirect in response.

*simple flow* : 
aaa.com ====> API Gateway & Lambda ==[302 redirect]==> *bbb.com*

It worked well when following [the blog](https://rpgreen.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/how-to-http-redirects-with-api-gateway-and-lambda/). However, I couldn't set cookie at *bbb.com*.

I followed the blog and defined another “Set-Cookie” header. My Lambda code snippet listed below.

```
context.succeed({
    location : "http://192.168.173.193:3030",
    setCookie: "path=/;sessionID=1234;domain=null;"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you update your Response Parameters?

In that blog post notice the `responseParameters` section of the Swagger Example.

```
responseParameters:
          method.response.header.Location: "integration.response.body.location"
```

You need to add another line to that mapping the `Set-Cookie` parameter. Something like:

```
responseParameters:
          method.response.header.Location: "integration.response.body.location"
          method.response.header.Set-Cookie: "integration.response.body.setCookie"
```