# serverless: When 302 redirect the custom header or set-cookie header not getting passed

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I am using aws api gateway with help of serverless. 
I am able to redirect to another domain from my lambda function.

like : abc.com ====> API Gateway & Lambda ==[302 redirect]==> xyz.com

I am unable to set custom header or any header.

here is my code.

```
exports.create = async (event) => {
  try {
    const token ='uniqueValue';
    const response = {
      statusCode: 302,
      headers: {
        Location: 'http://localhost:1337',
        bearer_token: token,
        'Set-Cookie': token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  };
  return response;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }
};
```

my `auth-handler.yml` looks like this,

```
auth-token:
    handler: modules/auth/endpoints/token.create
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: /rest/auth/token
          method: get
```

I am unable to set cookie in xyz.com. please help...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS API Gateway : Use 302 redirect and set-cookie header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595672/aws-api-gateway-use-302-redirect-and-set-cookie-header)

Comment: It's not a duplicate as I am not using any swagger.yml

Comment: The response of lambda is for ABC.com, not for xyz.com. The cookie is set for domain ABC.com.